# ggplot2 add data from additional data frame next to plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to be able to extend my boxplots with additional information. Here is a working example for ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)

# Basic box plot
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
# Rotate the box plot
p + coord_flip()
```

I would like to add additional information from a separate data frame. For example:

```
extra <- data.frame(dose=factor(c(0.5,1,2)), label=c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3"), n=c("n=42","n=52","n=35"))

> extra
  dose  label    n
1  0.5 Label1 n=42
2    1 Label2 n=52
3    2 Label3 n=35
```

I would like to create the following figure where the information to each dose (factor) is outside the plot and aligns with each of the dose levels (I made this in powerpoint as an example):

[image]

EDIT:
I would like to ask advice for an extension of the initial question.

What about this extension where I use fill to split up dose by the two groups?

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
ToothGrowth$group <- head(rep(1:2, 100), dim(ToothGrowth)[1])
ToothGrowth$group <- factor(ToothGrowth$group)

 p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=group)) + 
     geom_boxplot()
 # Rotate the box plot
 p + coord_flip()

extra <- data.frame(
  dose=factor(rep(c(0.5,1,2), each=2)), 
  group=factor(rep(c(1:2), 3)), 
  label=c("Label1A", "Label1B", "Label2A", "Label2B", "Label3A", "Label3B"), 
  n=c("n=12","n=30","n=20", "n=32","n=15","n=20")
)
```

Is it possible to align data from the new data frame (extra, 6 rows) with each of the dose/group combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `geom_text` with `clip = "off"` inside `coord_flip`:

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_text(
        y = max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.1,
        data = extra,
        aes(x = dose, label = sprintf("%s\n%s", label, n)),
        hjust = 0) +
    coord_flip(clip = "off") +
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"))
```

[image]

Explanation: We place text outside of the plot area with `geom_text` and disable clipping with `clip = "off"` inside `coord_flip`. Lastly, we increase the plot margin to accommodate the additional labels. You can adjust the vertical `y` position in the margin (so the horizontal position in the plot because of the coordinate flip) by changing the factor in `y =  max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.1`.

---

In response to your edit, here is a possibility

```
extra <- data.frame(
  dose=factor(rep(c(0.5,1,2), each=2)),
  group=factor(rep(c(1:2), 3)),
  label=c("Label1A", "Label1B", "Label2A", "Label2B", "Label3A", "Label3B"),
  n=c("n=12","n=30","n=20", "n=32","n=15","n=20")
)

library(tidyverse)
ToothGrowth %>%
    mutate(
        dose = as.factor(dose),
        group = as.factor(rep(1:2, nrow(ToothGrowth) / 2))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = dose, y = len, fill = group)) +
    geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
    geom_text(
        data = extra %>%
            mutate(
                dose = as.factor(dose),
                group = as.factor(group),
                ymax = max(ToothGrowth$len) * 1.1),
        aes(x = dose, y = ymax, label = sprintf("%s\n%s", label, n)),
        position = position_dodge(width = 1),
        size = 3,
        hjust = 0) +
    coord_flip(clip = "off", ylim = c(0, max(ToothGrowth$len))) +
    theme(
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 5, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

A few comments:

1. We ensure that labels match the dodged bars by using `position_dodge(with = 1)` inside `geom_text` and `geom_boxplot`.
2. It seems that `position_dodge` does not like a global `y` (outside of `aes`). So we include the y position for the labels in `extra` and use it inside `aes`. As a result, we need to explicitly limit the range of the `y` axis. We can do that inside `coord_flip` with `ylim = c(0, max(ToothGrowth$len))`.